# How to implement Javascript into modal if its recall from another php page

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

In index.php I have table with orders, when I click on order to modify,  a modal shows but from page call edit.php. Now as you see in the screen shot:

[image: Modal shows and call from seperate page]

I have many troubles, I can't implement any Javascript like datepicker, Google address autocomplete.

href in index.php:

```
 <a href="edit.php" data-toggle='modal' data-target = "#action2" class ="btn btn-primary"> <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit </a></a>
```

**Edit.php**

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");
$q_customer = $conn->query
    ("SELECT * from orders inner JOIN mydate on orders.order_no=mydate.order_no and orders.date=mydate.order_date" ) or die(mysqli_error());
$f_customer = $q_customer->fetch_array();
?>
<form method = "POST" action = "save_customer_query.php" enctype = "multipart/form-data" class = "modal-body" id = "action2">
    <center>
        <label class = "text-info">Update Order information</label>
    </center>
    <div class  = "modal-body">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
            <label for="name" class="control-label">Order Date</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "orderdatepicker"  id="orderdatepicker" value = "<?php echo $f_customer['date']?>" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
            <label for="name" class="control-label">Order Number</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "order_no"  id="order_no" tabindex="1" value = "<?php echo $f_customer['order_no']?>" class="form-control" autofocus />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
            <label for="name" class="control-label">Phone Number</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "phone"  id="phone" tabindex="1" class="form-control"  />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
            <label for="name" class="control-label">First Name</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "first_name"  id="first_name" tabindex="2" class = "form-control"  />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
            <label for="name" class="control-label">Last Name</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "last_name" id="last_name"tabindex="3" class = "form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
            <label for="name" class="control-label">Email</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "email"  id="email" tabindex="4" class = "form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
            <label for="name" class="control-label">Company</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "company"  id="company" tabindex="5" class = "form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
            <label for="name" class="control-label">Address</label>
            <div id="locationField">
                <input id="autocomplete" name = "address"  onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" class = "form-control" value = "<?php echo $f_customer['address']?>"/>
            </input>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <label for="timepicker_6" class="control-label">Kitchen Time </label>
        <input type="text"  id="timepicker_6" name = "k_time" value = "<?php echo $f_customer['k_time']?>" class = "form-control"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#timepicker_6').timepicker({
                    showPeriod: true,
                    showLeadingZero: true
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <label for="timepicker_7" class="control-label">Delivery Time </label>
        <input type="text" id="timepicker_7" name = "d_time" value = "<?php echo $f_customer['d_time']?>" class = "form-control"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#timepicker_7').timepicker({
                    showPeriod: true,
                    showLeadingZero: true 
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Driver</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "driver_no"  id="driver_no"  tabindex="5" class = "form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <label for="name" >No of People</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "no_ofppl"  id="no_ofppl" tabindex="5" class = "form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class = "form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
    <button  class = "btn btn-default" data-dismiss = "modal" ><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>
</div>
<div class = "modal-footer">
    <button  class = "btn btn-primary" name = "save" tabindex="7" id="save" ><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> Save</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Didn't added google api autocomplete script because its too long.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is instead of binding `timepicker` on `document.ready` method bind all time picker used in Modal popUp in On `modal shown` event just like below that's it do the same thing for **datepicker, google address autocomplete** as well to make it work..

```
$('#action2').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#timepicker_6').timepicker({
            showPeriod: true,
            showLeadingZero: true
     }); 

});
```

Comment: it should work though what error it throws in console?

Comment: I added this code before in index.php <script>
$('#mymodal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
window.location = "index.php"; 
</script> but did'nt excuted

Comment: is your id `#mymodal` correct it seems like it should be `#action2` ? and yes put it in `document.ready` as well

Comment: its #action2 ,  mistake, window.location works fine but not timepicker, even its working when i add new order but not on show modal to modify

Comment: it seems like on update order there is something wrong check your console what it says ?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).timepicker is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.js:4), <anonymous>:3:41)
    at fire (jquery-1.10.2.js?_=1486033436174:3048)
    at Object.add [as done] (jquery-1.10.2.js?_=1486033436174:3094)
    at init.ready (jquery-1.10.2.js?_=1486033436174:271)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.js:4), <anonymous>:2:34)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at jquery.js:4
    at Function.globalEval (jquery.js:4)
    at init.domManip (jquery.js:5)
    at init.append (jquery.js:5)

Comment: Ohhh than please make sure the function i have given in my answer has to be placed after `timepicker.js` and this `timepicker.js` is after `jquery-1.10.2.js`

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.timepicker.js?v=0.3.3"></script>
this link is after all links which calls javascript and css files, that what you means

Comment: yes the function should be after this js and this js should be after `jquery-1.10.2.js` js

Comment: here sort of links:
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include/ui-1.10.0/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include/ui-1.10.0/jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include/ui-1.10.0/jquery.ui.tabs.min.js"></script>
 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.timepicker.js?v=0.3.3"></script> why still picker doesn't appear in modal?

Comment: any help please

Comment: @VsauceCode from my side it looks fine , there are many possibilities some of the jquery might be conflicted but i'm not really sure about this because from this side i can't figure what exactly happening?